# Como tornar apenas a pasta webroot visivel para todos?

Tags: cakephp, segurança

Na documentação do Cake, indica [lá](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/deployment.html#check-your-security) que se deve ter apenas esta pasta visivel para todos. Como é que se pode fazer isso? Isto protege o código da minha aplicação de ser adulterado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### webroot

A pasta `webroot` automaticamente é visível para todos.

Se você observar nos `.htaccess` do CakePHP, verá que no final das contas tudo é redirecionado ela.

E como você certamente deve saber, se você acessar por exemplo:

- http://www.example.com/img/suaimagem.jpg
- http://www.example.com/css/theme.css
- etc

Terá o retorno do arquivo tranquilamente, ou seja: todo mundo tem acesso direto.

### permissões

Agora, quanto a permissões, normalmente eu seto o seguinte:

- 770 = `app/tmp`
- 770 = pasta de uploads
- 660 = o resto dos arquivos

Para adicionar estas permissões faça o seguinte:

```
chmod -R 660 /var/www/pasta_do_seu_site/
chmod -R 770 /var/www/pasta_do_seu_site/app/tmp/
chmod -R 770 /var/www/pasta_do_seu_site/app/webroot/uploads/
```

Troque `/var/www/pasta_do_seu_site/`, pelo diretório correto do seu servidor/máquina.

- `chmod` é o comando responsável por aplicar permissões no Linux
- `-R` significa recursivamente

Se no servidor tiver acesso apenas ao CPanel, há a possibilidade de ir no **folder explorer/navigator** e setar as permissões de cada pasta manualmente e/ou recursivamente.

**Tenha absoluta certeza da pasta que você informou para não ter problemas.**

No geral significa que:

- `tmp` e `uploads` precisam ter permissão de escrita, leitura e execução
- O resto dos arquivos precisam apenas de leitura e escrita
- Em ambos os casos, somente o usuário do servidor e/ou pertencente ao grupo dele que podem fazer isso. Qualquer outro usuário não pode.

---

Creio que seja isso.

Qualquer dúvida deixe um comentário.

Comment: Como é que eu posso adicionar essas permições?

Comment: Editei a resposta.